# Field not found after modifying mrp_production.py file odoo

Tags: python, odoo

A Quotation is been created, and a description has been written. Since this product is to be manufactured. A work order will be created.

[image]

The Work Order does not have the description line, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Thus, I modify the below file (**mrp_production_views.xml**)  to add the fields

line 111 `<field name="description" string="Description"/>`

and in **mrp_production.py**

```
description = fields.one2many('sale.order.line', 'name', related='sale.order_id', readonly=True)
```

Then I get this error. I'm sure the problem is in the above python statement.

> 2019-01-03 07:49:16,463 13284 INFO test werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - -
>   [03/Jan/2019 07:49:16] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 500 -
>   2019-01-03 07:49:16,467 13284 ERROR test werkzeug: Error on request:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 270, in
>   run_wsgi
>       execute(self.server.app)   File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 258, in
>   execute
>       application_iter = app(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 260, in app
>       return self.app(e, s)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py", line 166, in application
>       return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\service\wsgi_server.py",
>   line 154, in application_unproxied
>       result = handler(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1319, in **call**
>       return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 1474, in dispatch
>       odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo__init__.py", line 76, in registry
>       return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 61, in
>   **new**
>       return cls.new(db_name)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 85, in new
>       odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   11.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 376, in load_modules
>       force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   11.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 274, in load_marked_modules
>       perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo
>   11.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 152, in load_module_graph
>       registry.setup_models(cr)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 277, in setup_models
>       model._setup_fields()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2425, in _setup_fields
>       field.setup_full(self)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 471, in setup_full
>       self._setup_related_full(model)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 508, in
>   _setup_related_full
>       field = target._fields[name] KeyError: 'manufacturing_lead'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a many2one field in sale_order_line as below

```
mrp_id = fields.Many2one('mrp.production',string="MRP")
```

Create the description field in mrp_production as below:

```
description = fields.one2many('sale.order.line', 'mrp_id', related='sale.order_line', readonly=True)
```

Please ensure that sale field (Many2one) should be there in mrp_production, so that you can call sale.order_line

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

description = fields.one2many(related='sale.order_id', readonly=True)

Comment: does not work..  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 250, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 428, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name)
TypeError: Model 'mrp.production' does not exist in registry.